# html rendered with php and rendered with javascript has different design

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have included 4 csss files in my index.php  inside

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/media.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/media.index.css">
```

I know it is not good idea to make a lot of HTTP requests but later I will combine them so this shouldn't be any problem.

Right now I am making a website where user can find most popular movies and search movies. One of the feature is to send API request and show result as image gallery. In the beginning, I used Javascript to receive api result and render it.

```
 class fetchModel {
   constructor(){
      this.isIndex = null;
      this.doesQueryExist = null;
      this.url = window.location.href;
  }
  async sendFetch() {
    const hash = await this.url.split('?')[1];
    if(!hash){
        let fetchResponse = await fetch('http://localhost/movieMovie/popular.php');
        let fetchedJSON = await fetchResponse.json();
        if (window.location.href.endsWith('/')){
            fetchedJSON.length = 6;
            this.doesQueryExist = false;
        }
        return fetchedJSON;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
}
class fetchView {
renderFetch(fetchData) {
    let figure, image, movieDataJSON;
    let divElement = $('<div></div>');
    for (let i = 0; i < fetchData.length; i++) {
        movieDataJSON = JSON.parse(fetchData[i]);
        figure = $('<figure class="col-8 col-sm-4"></figure>');
        image = $('<img alt="' + movieDataJSON.Title + '">');
        image.attr('src', movieDataJSON.Poster);
        figure.append(image);
        if ($(window).width() < 576 && i == 0) {
            figure.addClass('active');
        }
        divElement.append(figure);
        if(window.location.href.endsWith('/')){
            divElement.insertAfter('#MostlyRecommended>div:first-child');
        }else{
            divElement.insertAfter('#Results>div:first-child');
        }
    }
  }
 }
 class fetchController {
constructor(model, view) {
    this.model = model;
    this.view = view;
    this.model.sendFetch().then(data => this.fetchedData(data));
}
fetchedData(data) {
    if(!this.model.doesQueryExist){
        this.view.renderFetch(data);
    }
}
}
const fetchModelObject = new fetchModel();
const fetchViewObject = new fetchView();
const fetchControllerObject = new fetchController(fetchModelObject, fetchViewObject);
```

and this works great,

[image]

this is the design if I do it with javascript, fine. But later I thought instead of php sending a fetch to popular.php with javascript, it can just include popular.php directly.

Like this,

```
<section id="MostlyRecommended">
        <div>
            <h1>MOST POPULAR</h1>
        </div>
        <?php 
            include 'popular.php';
        ?>
        <div>
            <?php 

                for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
                    $array = json_decode($posterArray[$i]);
            ?>
                <figure class="col-8 col-sm-4">
                    <img alt="<?php echo $array->Title?>" src="<?php echo $array->Poster?>">
                </figure>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="sliderButtonContainer">
            <div>
                <span class="slider active"></span>
                <span class="slider"></span>
                <span class="slider"></span>
                <span class="slider"></span>
                <span class="slider"></span>
                <span class="slider"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

$posterArray is an array from popular.php .

Added a new div after the first div in section#MostlyRecommended and made a for loop to render figure, which is 100% equivalent to

```
divElement.insertAfter('#MostlyRecommended>div:first-child');
```

in jQuery

but the design which I see is

[image]

you see, I get totally different and ugly design.
What can be the reason?

Comment: It may be worth looking at the HTML page they both generate and see if you can work out what the differences are.  This may give the best ideas of what needs to be done.

Comment: Are the `id` or `classnames` dynamically generated?

Comment: @dev-aentgs chrome web browser automatically creates wfd-id for the wrapper div on both codes but figures don't have any id. bootstrap classes col-8 col-sm-4 are generated correctly.

Comment: Ok, like @NigelRen suggested finding diff between both page sources might give better hints

Comment: @dev-aentgs I don't know what do you mean "DYNAMICALLY GENERATED" but I used these codes to render that problematic part...